# Адаптировать блок div с фоновым изображением

Tags: html, css

Использую блок следующего вида `<div class="wrappmainslide"></div>`

Использую стиль следующего вида:

```
.wrappmainslide{
  width: 100%;
  height: 636px;
  background-image: url(../img/mainslide.png);
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Высота задана из учета высоты изображения.

Применение `height: auto;` тут не подходит. При изменении размера окна, высота блока остается неизменной, а картинка повторяется. Как правильно адаптировать это?

Comment: `background-size: cover` ?

Comment: дело в высоте блока ,а не  background-size

Comment: Используйте @media all and (max-width: ширина){ .wrappmainslide{ height: ваша высота; }  } и так для всех устройств и размеров экрана

Comment: Соотношение сторон у картинки фиксированное? Можете указать какое?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov. да она 1680 на 636

Comment: я более менее решил проблему,заменив background обычной картинкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий код. Значение `padding-top` - это частное от деления высоты на ширину.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: url(http://beerhold.it/1680/636) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  padding-top: 37.87514285%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```